# Value of type 'Int' has no member 'seconds'

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have tried many ways, but I still can't convert the timestamp to date (year month day..), now I have this problem，

problem appear Value of type 'Int' has no member 'seconds'
(已解決)

---

Here is my edited code, but the time is showing on Xcode instead of the simulator
[如圖片中顯示](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiq0n.png)

code: VC

```
 if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? TimeInterval {
     let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
     let today = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
     print("Time Stamp's Current Time:\(today)")
     let post = Post(email: email, caption: caption, imageUrl: imageURL, timestamp: timestamp)
...
...
...
...
cell.timeLabel.text = String(postArray[indexPath.row].timestamp)
```

code: Post

```
 struct Post {
    var email:String
    var caption:String
    var imageUrl:String
    var timestamp:Double

    init(email:String,caption:String,imageUrl:String,timestamp:Double) {
        self.email = email
        self.caption = caption
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

Comment: `as? Int` converts to an Int, right?  How about `as? Timestamp` ?

Comment: If not INT, what should I convert to?

Comment: `if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? Timestamp { let date = timestamp.dateValue() }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have converted something from a network response into an `Int`. You have then called `<int>.seconds`. The error message is telling you that there is no such thing as `.seconds` on an Int.

The timestamp that the `Date` class is expecting is simply a `Double`. You can use either the keyboard "Double" or "TimeInterval". Instead of casting as an Int, just do this:

```
if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? TimeInterval {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
```

Comment: I tried it before and got this X->Cannot to convert a value of type "Timestamp" to the expected parameter type "TimeInterval" (aka "Double")

Comment: @ERIC apologies that was a typo while reading something unrelated. Yes the name iOS uses is "TimeInterval" not "TimeStamp". I've edited the answer, simply use `TimeInterval`

Comment: I changed to " if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? TimeInterval {
                                        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)"
, a yellow reminder "Initialization of immutable value 'date' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it"

Comment: And my tableView cell also reminded, cell.timeLabel.text = String(postArray[indexPath.row].timestamp)-->Value of type 'Post' has no member 'timestamp'

Comment: What should I do please? Thank you very much for your teaching, there are so many questions sorry, this has been bothering me for a long time

Comment: @ERIC if you are copy / pasting code from somewhere online, you need to stop and take a minute to make sure you are actually reading and understanding what you are doing. You need to read tutorials online, read the swift book etc before attempting this. The yellow warning is extremely clear, look at the code you have. You create "let date = ..." and then don't use it. You pass the timestamp (double) into your post object, not the date object. As for why you can't access timestamp, you've not posted any of that code, most likely its not marked as public

Comment: I know the meaning of the yellow code, I want to say.. The reason for the yellow code "not used" after using the above teaching post, I'm very sorry

Comment: @ERIC the warning has nothing to do with the code I gave you. Your code wasn't compiling because there was no `.seconds`. I fixed that error, it compiled. After compiling it found that the variable wasn't used and gave a warning

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved a lot of troubles for me, I revised the question, what is the reason?

Comment: @ERIC i've already answered this above. You are not reading your own code, or my responses. Your object `Post` has a variable called `timestamp`, it is a Double. You get a double from the network, convert it to a date, print it and then it gets thrown away and never used. You pass the double into your `Post` object and then display the double in your cell. Change the variable type inside `Post` to a `Date`. (`var timestamp: Date`)

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply, maybe it's a translation problem I still can't understand.. Is the POST changed to this? (var timestamp:Date)
After I changed it to this ( cell.timeLabel.text = postArray[indexPath.row].timestamp ) it shows red warning again

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is just an int (number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)).
So doesn't have a seconds property.
Have you tried:
 `let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)` ???

Comment: I tried it and got this X->Cannot convert value of type 'Timestamp' to expected argument type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')